# how can vectors not be of unit norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonality

I have a Linear homework questions asking what the QR factorization of a matrix A whose columns are orthogonal but not of unit norm might look like. I reread the section in textbook about norms, but still don't get how vectors cannot be of unit norm (I'm assuming this means 1-norm). Doesn't this just mean that I'm adding the absolute values of all values in each vector? So how could a vector not have it's values added? In my mind every vector is of unit norm, no?

Thanks in advance, I'm sure the question is silly but I had to ask.

Comment: Unit norm means they have length one $\| v\|=1$

Comment: Does $(1,2)$ have unit norm?

Comment: Note that in the context of the QR factorization, we're always talking about a norm with an associated inner product, so definitely not the 1-norm. Most commonly it's the 2-norm though it could be various other "inner-product-able" norms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been stated in the comments, a vector of unit norm has length one: $||v||_1=1$. The subscribt one here denotes we're talking about the 1-norm as you are suggesting. So if $$v=\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\-5\end{pmatrix},$$ then the 1-norm of this vector will be the sum of its elements in absolute value, so: $$|3|+|4|+|-5|=12.$$

Since 12 is not equal to 1, this vector is not of unit norm.

Comment: thank you my good sir

Comment: @saucin' No problem. Since you're new: here on Math Stackexchange we usually only use comments to ask for more details, to supply more details or to give helpful feedback. Appreciation for an answer or question can be given in the form of an upvote.